# How to convert dictionary keys as column names and values as rows in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary with a lot of records. I converted a numpy file into this dictionary. Both the numpy file and the dictioary have similar structures except the first two elements '{0' in the dictionary. Some of the records are shown below:

```
dct = {0:
        {
         'aa': {
               '11':  [0]
               '22':  [0]
               '433': [1]
               }, 

         'ab': {
               '11':   [1]
               '33':   [1]
               '433':  [1]
               '1400': [1]
               }, 


        'ac': {
               '18':   [2]
               '45':   [2]
               '430':  [2]
               '1400': [1]
               '1544': [2]
              },
      .... so on
        }
```

I need to convert it into a dataframe. I used the following code:

```
 data = []
   for k, v in dct.items():
      for t, val in v.items():
          for p, vall in val.items():
            data.append({
              'Name': t,
              'Key': p,
              'value': vall,
            })

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('outPutFile.csv', encoding='utf-8')
print(df)
```

With this code i am getting the following dataframe structure:

```
    Name,   Key,      value
     aa,    11,        [0]
     aa,    22,        [0]
     aa,    433        [1]
     ab,    11,        [1]
     ab,    33,        [1]
     ab,    433,       [1]
     ab,    1400,      [1]
     ac,    18,        [2]
     ac,    45,        [2]
     ac,    430,       [2]
     ac,    1400,      [1]
     ac,    1544,      [2]
     ...... and so on
```

I don't require the keys as rows. I need each key as a column name and the value as a row. Also, the square brackets around the numbers in Value need to be removed. The required dataframe is:

```
    Name,    11, 18, 22, 33, 45, 430, 433, 1400, 1544,
     aa,      0,  ,   0,   ,   ,    ,   1,     ,     ,
     ab,      1,  ,    ,  1,   ,    ,   1,    1,     ,    .... and so on
     ac,       , 2,    ,   ,  2,   2,    ,    1,    2,
```

I will really appreciate some help..

Thank you.

Comment: I don't get why many people use `dict` for their variables. This is 3rd time I see it on SO today alone :-).

Comment: @Quang Hoang, I changed it. Happy now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this dictionary:

```
dct = {0:
        {
         'aa': {
               '11': [0],
               '12': [0],
               '13': [1],
               }, 

         'ab': {
               '11': [1],
               '12': [1],
               '13': [1],
               '14': [1],
               }, 


        'ac': {
               '11': [2],
               '12': [2],
               '13': [2],
               '14': [1],
               '15': [2],
              }}}
```

You can do the following to create the desired dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dct[0]).transpose().rename_axis('Names')
df

       11   12  13  14  15
Names                   
aa    [0]   [0] [1] NaN NaN
ab    [1]   [1] [1] [1] NaN
ac    [2]   [2] [2] [1] [2]
```

All that is missing is changing all the values from list to the actual value inside:

```
for col in df:
    for name in df.index:
        if type(df.loc[name,col]) == list:
            df.loc[name,col] = df.loc[name,col][0]
df

       11   12  13  14  15
Names                   
aa     0    0   1   NaN NaN
ab     1    1   1   1   NaN
ac     2    2   2   1   2
```

Comment: @jib_gouveia, Thanks a lot for the help. I am using Spyder IDE and strangely, when i execute the code it goes into a non-ending loop. The example i provided is just few records and the dictionary contains a lot of records. Another thing, i am converting a numpy file into a dictionary and both have identical structures except the first two elements '{ 0' in the dictionary which are extra. That might have to do something with it ?

Comment: @codeDB before running the loop, is the dataframe in the format that you want? That is, is it correct except the values are within these brackets []? If those are correct, then the problem may be that the loop is inefficient, as it changes each value individually. Still, I would ask you to please run it with the dictionary I provided in the edit I am making to the answer, to see if the loop stops on your side.

Comment: I checked it and before i run the loop, The df that you converted with renaming the index is not in the format i need. It is showing a very strange format in which names are repeated multiple times in Names column. Even some of the values in square brackets are merged with names in the column.

Comment: If the names are repeated multiple times, the problem may lie in there. I have updated again the answer so you can see the output of the dataframe on that stage.

Comment: I tried your code with the short example i provided and its working file. May b something is wrong with my dictionary structure. As the names are not repeated in Names column. There are 7000 names as rows so its correct but the the other columns are repeated and where the column keys should be 50 in total with 50 values for all 7000 names but it shows like 21,000 keys which means the keys are repeated and values are also divided into these 21000 columns with some rows showing blanks. I try to check the dictionary again and see where is the problem. I will update the dictionary later.

Comment: I found the problem why i am not getting it right with my dictionary with all the records. The keys are not all common in all records. Some of them might be similar in different records but not all of them are same. Although they are in sequence like 10, 11, 23 ,450 etc. for each record. I updated the dictionary.

Comment: so did it work after the update on your dictionary?

Comment: I think it is working but i am not sure because with 21000 keys and 7000 rows, it was difficult to track the changes. Can you please once run your code on the dictionary i updated in the question. You will get the idea about the problem and the structure i get.

Comment: It works the same with the new values you added. Only difference is that the columns are not sorted, but that can be easily solved

Comment: @jib_qouveia, Thanks a lot. Its working perfectly fine except the column sorting. Sorry for giving you unnecessary trouble because of putting wrong dictionary keys at the first place and the keys are not just 50 in number and that was the misunderstanding that lead to all the trouble. Thank you  for taking so much time so solve it.

Comment: No problem @codeDB. Please accept the answer, to confirm it as correct